# Why I can't set up JTable with Table columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, columnheader

I use  my JTable, my JTableModel for my project. I can not start the table with my column headers and empty data. May you help me? Thank you.
Here is my code

MainCode class

```
  public class MainCode extends JFrame{
       public MainCode(){
  ...........other codes here........
  MyTableModel tm= new MyTableModel();
  MyTable table=new MyTable(tm);
  //JTable table=new JTable(tm); if I write this line,I see column names.
  table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(480,80));
  table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
  JScrollPane scrollPanetable=new JScrollPane(table);
  frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPanetable)
  ........another codes...........  

 }
}
```

MyTable class

```
public class MyTable extends JTable{
public MyTable(){

}
public MyTable(int row,int col){
    super(row,col);
}
@Override
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e){
    super.tableChanged(e);
    repaint();
    System.out.println("public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)");
}
```

}

MyTableModel class

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{
   private String[] columnNames; 
   private Object[][] data;
public MyTableModel(){
    super();
    columnNames=new String[]{"A","B","C"};
    data=new Object[][]{ {null,null,null}};
}
public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnNames.length;
}

public int getRowCount() {
    return data.length;
}

public String getColumnName(int col) {
    return columnNames[col];
}

public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    return data[row][col];
}
 }
```

it is not started with column names. What is wrong with this code.I see below image.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are creating MyTable with "new MyTable(tm)" expression? And are you sure you do not have "public MyTable(MyTableModel tm){}" constructor in MyTable?

Comment: public MyTable(MyTableModel tm){
        super(tm);
}
I added this code into MyTable class. It works.Thank you Meraman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you do not have constructor in `MyTable` which takes parameter `MyTableModel`.

You are creating table like this:

```
MyTable table=new MyTable(tm);
```

So you must have constructor in MyTable like this:

```
class MyTable extends JTable {

   public MyTable(MyTableModel tm){
        super(tm);
    }
}
```

If you have `MyTable` code that you posted here, your code will not compile!

Comment: I cuted MyTable class. I just posted important part

Answer (score 1):

More than likely you have not added the `JTable` in a `JScrollPane` which will cause the column names to be hidden

```
add(new JScrollPane(table));
```

Comment: I changed my post. I wrote JScrollPane line.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why are you overriding JTable?

Your own comment, `if I write this line,I see column names` suggests that your overriding of JTable is the problem.  You have an overridden implementation of `tableChanged(...)`, which the docs say `Application code will not use these explicitly, they are used internally by JTable.`  Otherwise, your subclassed JTable isn't doing anything special to warrant subclassing.

If you must subclass, you have to tell the subclass how to use your model, which you haven't done (either via a constructor or `setModel(...)`).

Comment: Because I want to create 3 different table that have different column names in same page.So I will use switch command to select which table will be created.

Comment: I can't say that I agree with that strategy, but if you must, then I'd put the switch (to return the proper column name) in the TableModel.

Comment: I will notice your comment while writing TableModel class.